# Are there valid scenarios when we should put multiple applications into the same container ? or multiple containers to pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

I am java developer and my devops expertice is not deep. Currently we use containers everywhere: docker, k8s etc.

In most cases we put single application into separated container, put it into separated k8s pod.
Is there ant scenarious when we should put

- 2 or more applications into the same container
- 2 or more containers into the same pod ?

Comment: Google "Kubernetes sidecar"

Answer (score 2):

Multiple containers `in a Pod`:

Helper or side application to your main application -- Called `Side-Car` containers. example of side-car containers would be: back-up container, Authentication, Synchronising, etc

---

Also we have `Pause Containers`:

- `Pause` container in each Pod
- Also called `sandbox` containers
- Reserve and holds network namespace
- Enables communication between containers

---

More Resources:

- [Learn Sidecar Container Pattern](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/kubernetes-learn-sidecar-container-pattern-6d8c21f873d)

Answer (score 0):

Sidecar containers are containers that are needed to run alongside the main container. The two containers share resources like pod storage and network interfaces. The sidecar containers can also share storage volumes with the main containers, allowing the main containers to access the data in the sidecars.